# stored function using time datatype not working

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench, stored-functions

```
`DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION am_or_pm (crying_time TIME)
RETURNS varchar(20) 
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 
DECLARE am_or_pm varchar(20)
IF  crying_time <= "11:59:00" THEN 
set am_or_pm = 'AM';
ELSEIF crying_time >= "12:00:00" THEN
SET am_or_pm = 'PM';`
```

trying to create a stored function that will sort time into AM and PM

Answer (score 0):

You need to terminate the commands with a semicolon (;) and have matching END. Also, instead of ELSEIF you can do ELSE:

```
CREATE FUNCTION am_or_pm(crying_time TIME)
RETURNS char(2) 
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 

DECLARE am_or_pm varchar(20);

IF (crying_time < "12:00:00") THEN 
  SET am_or_pm = 'AM';
ELSE 
  SET am_or_pm = 'PM';
END IF;

return am_or_pm;

end
```

A shorter version would be:

```
CREATE FUNCTION am_or_pm(crying_time TIME)
RETURNS char(2) 
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 

return if (crying_time < "12:00:00", "AM", "PM");

end
```